# Changing default values in settings.json in [Extension Development Host]

Tags: json, typescript, vscode-extensions

Hey I am writing an extension in VS Code, when I am running the extension at the initial running of the extension, I want to add a pop up with a text message input,and with that exact input I would like to change the default of settings.json.[image: n]

for now I need to change it directly in my project at "allinone.fileExtensions" and what I want to do is to change it with the input user at the intial running of my extension

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should specify your desired *setting* in your *package.json* file:

```json
"configuration": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "Your Extension Name",
            "properties": {
                "your-extension-name.setting": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"],
                    "default": null,
                    "markdownDescription": "A short description"
                }
            }
}
```

The *type* property might differ depending on your configuration setting. See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration) for additional information

---

You can then check if the value is still *null* and update it accordingly:

```js
const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('your-extension-name');
if (!(config.has("setting") && config.get("setting") !== null)) {
    vscode.window.showInputBox({ title: "Enter value: "}).then(value => {
        config.update("setting", value, vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global);
    });
}
```

---

However, you might want to use globalState/localState and VSCode's [Memento API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Memento) ([A short explanation here](https://www.chrishasz.com/blog/2020/07/28/vscode-how-to-use-local-storage-api/)), if it suits your use-case better.